# Calculating how many years from "from - to" date form in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, date

I have a form here (https://nursinggroup.com/pharmacist-profile/) where users will put in a date in the form of "mm / yy" for bot a "from" input box and a "to" input box. After the user goes through and adds in all their dates, they submit the form and a PDF is created using Gravity Forms PDF Extended (mPDF). What I need to happen is that during the creation of the PDF I need it to calculate the values for each item and spit out the total amount of years onto the PDF for each one.

So for example, if I enter in the following entries on the online form:

```
Ambulatory Care    "From: 02 / 88"   "To: 02 / 98"
Home Healthcare    "From: 07 / 02"   "To: 07 / 05"
Oncology           "From: 09 / 06"   "To: 05 / 12"
```

On the PDF it would spit out the following:

```
Ambulatory Care    10
Home Healthcare    3
Oncology           5.8
```

I have read through and tried many different code samples out there, but I am just not skilled enough with this type of PHP to make this work. A few other things to keep in mind. This is on a WordPress site, using Gravity Forms for the forms, and Gravity Forms PDF Extended to create the PDF's from those forms. Another thing to note, is that the entry of the year must remain in `yy` format versus `yyyy` The user does not fill in a day as well, only `mm / yy`

```
<?php

  // Set timezone
  date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

  // Time format is UNIX timestamp or
  // PHP strtotime compatible strings
  function dateDiff($time1, $time2, $precision = 6) {
    // If not numeric then convert texts to unix timestamps
    if (!is_int($time1)) {
      $time1 = strtotime($time1);
    }
    if (!is_int($time2)) {
      $time2 = strtotime($time2);
    }

    // If time1 is bigger than time2
    // Then swap time1 and time2
    if ($time1 > $time2) {
      $ttime = $time1;
      $time1 = $time2;
      $time2 = $ttime;
    }

    // Set up intervals and diffs arrays
    $intervals = array('year','month','day','hour','minute','second');
    $diffs = array();

    // Loop thru all intervals
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
      // Create temp time from time1 and interval
      $ttime = strtotime('+1 ' . $interval, $time1);
      // Set initial values
      $add = 1;
      $looped = 0;
      // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
      while ($time2 >= $ttime) {
        // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
        $add++;
        $ttime = strtotime("+" . $add . " " . $interval, $time1);
        $looped++;
      }

      $time1 = strtotime("+" . $looped . " " . $interval, $time1);
      $diffs[$interval] = $looped;
    }

    $count = 0;
    $times = array();
    // Loop thru all diffs
    foreach ($diffs as $interval => $value) {
      // Break if we have needed precission
      if ($count >= $precision) {
 break;
      }
      // Add value and interval 
      // if value is bigger than 0
      if ($value > 0) {
 // Add s if value is not 1
 if ($value != 1) {
   $interval .= "s";
 }
 // Add value and interval to times array
 $times[] = $value . " " . $interval;
 $count++;
      }
    }

    // Return string with times
    return implode(", ", $times);
  }

?>
```

Comment: Is that format fixed? Parse the input `#^From: (\d{2}) / (\d{2})$#`, `#^To: (\d{2}) / (\d{2})$#` and take a look at the DateTime, DateDiff and DateInterval classes.

Comment: The format is fixed and can not be changed. I will take a look at those right now, and I kind of already have, but I have not been able to wrap my head around making this code work. Not skilled enough to write it from scratch, and I am having difficulties manipulating other's existing code using those classes you mentioned above.

Comment: so what do you looking for? a function you can use to make the calculation? or have you even looked at the form handle code?

Comment: I guess what I would need is a function. Right now I have the entire file already coded, calling to all of the form entries from the database and I have them printing out on the PDF. Basically all I guess I need is a function that will take the "starting" date and the "ending" date variables and spit out how many years are in between them, assign that number a variable and then I can do the rest from there.

Comment: You know SO is here to assist you on gettings things right ... on your own? Post what you've tried and we may tell you what's wrong. Also, where do you make the cut which two-digit year belongs to 1900 and which to 2000? Is 01 / 50 1950 or 2050?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I didn't post what I had because they are from other SO posts and I don't think they are on the right track with what I need to get done exactly. This is what I have so far though, but I do not know how to break down my format of `mm / yy` and how to have it apply to the entries from the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create separate fields for the calculated numbers. This way you can output them directly in the PDF via the entry ID rather than having to run any custom during the PDF creation process.

To calculate the number of years, I would recommend using something like this:

http://gravitywiz.com/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates/

It will calculate the number of days; however, it could be easily modified to calculate the number of years by changing this line:

```
dayCount = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 );
```

...to this:

```
dayCount = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 360 * 1000 );
```

You could rename the variable as well but you'll need to replace it everywhere it is referenced in the current scope.

Comment: David this looks like it is very close to what I am looking for! I am going to mess around with it a little bit right now and get back to you. Do you foresee any issues with this pulling from my custom field versus the date field the demo is illustrating?

Comment: Hey David, so after looking over you suggestion and the code over at Gravity Wiz I decided to go for it and it looks like it will work for what I need. I went through and changed all my custom input fields to be date picker fields now so that it will work and everything is working great! The one issue I am having though is that the code is rounding the amount of years. So instead of it spitting out 4.5 years it is showing 5 years. Any ideas on how I can get it to spit out the exact amount in decimal form to one placeholder?

Comment: Hey Brendan, the rounding happens here: 

    dayCount = Math.round( dayCount ) + this.options.countAdjust;

If you want the exact decimal value, you can just do:

    dayCount = dayCount + this.options.countAdjust;

Remember to mark this as the correct answer if you go with it. ;)

Comment: I spoke a bit to soon. That indeed does give me a decimal but it does not however round the decimal to the nearest tenth. So what I need it to do is round  `1.6588598   =>   1.7` Can you let me know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You can round to one decimal like so: dayCount = ( Math.round( dayCount * 10 ) / 10 ) + this.options.countAdjust;

Comment: @DavefromGravityWiz How can I show the age, months and day????

Comment: @ZakirHossain Do you mean like the age in years and then the remainder months and days? I demonstrated how this is possible with Date Time Calculator for one of our customers here: https://www.loom.com/share/d86228505a2147b9973c98aad6bb2631